# Join columns if one of them is null

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 columns:

```
col1, int 
col2, char(10) 
col3, char(11)
```

only one of them has any value in them, and it can be either one of them.

i want to check which columns are null and add the one, whcih has a value to a fourth column: col4.

i use T-SQL

Comment: Don't store data like that.

Comment: you dont state what database you are using. However check out the `Coalesce` statement. That should do it for you.

Comment: Col4's data type?

Comment: Hi. Got it, will remember that for future use.

Comment: Column 4s datatype is the one that makes most sense, so char.

Comment: it is t-sql, microsoft sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), col1), CONVERT(CHAR(11), col2), col3)
FROM yourtable;
```

[TSQL: COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select col1,col2,col3, coalesce(col1, coalesce(col2,col3)) as col4
from your_table
```

> COALESCE returns the first non-null expr in the expression list. If all occurrences of expr evaluate to null, then the function returns null.

Comment: Why the coalesce inside the coalesce? Why not just `coalesce(col1,col2,col3)` ?

Comment: this is because TS don't specify what DB he uses. Firebird for example support only two args.

Comment: Note that the columns' data types don't match.

Comment: If no DBMS is specified, ANSI SQL is assumed.

Comment: its t sql, sorry for not specifying

Answer (score 3):

You could use `IS NULL` comparison to return a boolean true or false for each column and `COALESCE()` to find the first non-null value among all the columns

```
SELECT
  col1 IS NULL AS col1_null,
  col2 IS NULL AS col2_null,
  col3 IS NULL AS col3_null,
  COALESCE(cast(col1 as char(11)), cast(col2 as char(11)), cast(col3 as char(11)) AS first_not_null_val
FROM table
```

Order of columns provided within `COALESCE()` function matters, but since you have only one of those three that is not null, then it would always return that one.

*Note*: You need to cast your columns to the same datatype for `COALESCE()`. Since your upper bound is `char(11)` because it covers both `char(10)` and `int` type I've come up with that. I imagine that you want to keep the spaces which is why you use `char` in the first place.

Comment: Note that the columns' data types don't match.

Comment: Thanks!!. The database has different types, i am cleaning the tables, so they become more useable